# Rewrite relative URLs to absolute URLs via jQuery

Tags: jquery

Features:

- The site is on different mirrors.
- JavaScript in an external file, it is the same for all mirrors.
- All external files are in the folder "assets".
- The ability to launch a site in the local file system.

Have code:

```
<link href="assets/css/example.css">
<script src="assets/js/example.js"></script>
```

Result:

```
<link href="http://different.domain/assets/css/example.css">
<script src="http://different.domain/assets/js/example.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's question. How to rewrite relative URLs to absolute URLs via jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for script tags which already have a full url in the src and those which do not have a src at all.  For example:

```
$(function(){
    var domain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/';
    $('script').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if( 'undefined' !== typeof src && '' != src  && !src.match(/^https?:/) ){
            $(this).attr('src', domain + src);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Incorrect result in the local file system: 
<script src="file:///assets/js/example.js"></script>

Comment: Missed that requirement.  How is it meant to behave in the local file system?  Is the "domain root" the folder the page is in or should everything be relative to the file root?  I think you'd have to handle the case where location.protocol == 'file:' as a special case when defining var domain.

Comment: Thank you! You helped a lot. Dwell on the current version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$(function() {
$("script[src]").each(function() {
$(this).attr("src",location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname+"/"+$(this).attr("src"));
});
});
```

Comment: Incorrect result in the local file system: 
<script src="file:///assets/js/example.js"></script>